# Angular HttpClient Pagination for View

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have a Service with a method like so:

```
 public getAlerts(page: number, opts?: AlertRequestOptionsInterface): Observable<AlertInterface[]> {
    const path = `/alerts/list`;
    const body = { page: page, ...opts };
    return this._http.post<AlertInterface[]>(path, body, { headers: headers })
        .catch(() => Observable.of(undefined));
}
```

And I'm binding it into my view like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-alerts',
  templateUrl: 'alerts.html',
})
export class AlertsPage {

  public alerts: Observable<AlertInterface[]>;
  public subscription: Subscription;
  public loading: boolean = true;

  constructor(private _alerts: AlertsService) { }

  public ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.alerts = this._alerts.getAlerts(1);
    this.subscription = this.alerts.subscribe(() => {
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }

  public ionViewWillLeave() {
     this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

If I wanted to paginate and append the next page API call onto my `Observable<AlertInterface[]>` how would I go about doing that on the view side of things?

Comment: This code is already buggy: if the view uses `async` to display the alerts, then you'll make two separate HTTP requests: one to load and display the results, and a second one to load the results and set the loading flag to false once loaded. Just make it simple, and store the array of alerts in your component instead of storing the observable. To get the next page, call a method of your component, that will call the service again, andstore the new array in the component again. There are other ways to do it using observables, you'd better keep things simple for now.

Comment: Thanks! I really like the idea of using the `async` flag, but it seems very unusable for HTTP calls w/ pagination. Seems better for things like user interactions (mouse movements) or statuses. Not sure why Angular is gung-ho on them over Promises.

Comment: Using the async pipe is fine, provided that you really understand and master observables. But this shows you don't master them yet (which is fine: they're quite complex beasts). So I'd stick to simpler stuff if I were you (and I usually do myself).